# Can I obtaine a List of objects with a stream?

Tags: java

I have a list of objects:

```
public class User{
String name;
String hobby;
}
```

And concrete

```
User1 = { name1, hobby1 }
User2 = { name1, hobby2 }
User3 = { name2, hobby1 }
User4 = { name1, hobby3 }
```

I want to obtain now an object containing :

```
public class HobbySortedByUserName{
String name;
List<String> hobbys;
}
```

Result will be:

```
List<HobbySortedByUserName> list;
First element:
{ "name1", [ "hobby1", "hobby2", "hobby3"]}
Seconde element:
{ "name2", [ "hobby1" ])
```

If I use streams, I can obtain this as a Map<String, List < String > > . But I want to have a List of Objects and not a map.

I can do a new Stream from the map, and map each value in the object, but I don't think that a good practise, as I do 2 times a Stream.

How can I achieve them?

Comment: `public class Object{` won't compile, but can you please clarify what output you're expecting? Are you trying to group the user's hobbies by their names? If so, what's wrong with a Map object?

Comment: Your question is not clear as to what is expected in the output. Your class name is HobbySortedByUserName so it should have two variables - String hobby and List<String> userNames. Can you please recheck your question and confirm.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your map to list with `Map` api like

```
map.entrySet()
            .stream().map(e -> new YourDesiredObject<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to (1) group `User` objects by name, which internally utilizes `Map`, as well as you want to (2) present `Map`-like data as `List`. I am afraid the Stream API is not so powerful to satisfy both your requirements using single stream.

You can directly create result object (BTW please rename your custom class to something specific, the name `Object` attracts downvotes to otherwise good question) in downstream collector of `groupingBy` but still you need extra stream to flatten map entry values into result list:

```java
listOfUsers.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(User::getName, collectingAndThen(toList(), l -> new YourObject(l.get(0).getName(), l.stream().map(User::getHobby).collect(toList())))))
        .values().stream()
        .collect(toList());
```

which is code I definitely don't want to get for code review.

---

**Original answer (no longer valid, thanks to @shmosel):**

Just transform map entries:

```java
listOfUsers.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(User::getName, mapping(User::getHobby, toList())))
        // you are here now ^
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new YourObject(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
        .collect(toList());
```

Comment: OP doesn't want this: *I can do a new Stream from the map, and map each value in the object, but I don't think that a good practise, as I do 2 times a Stream.*

Comment: @shmosel thanks, I edited answer. This is type of question for which there is no "beautiful" answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
List<UserHobbies> grouped = users.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::getName))
        .collect(LinkedList::new,
                (list, user) -> {
                    if (list.isEmpty() || !list.getLast().getName().equals(user.getName())) {
                        list.add(new UserHobbies(user.getName()));
                    }
                    list.getLast().addHobby(user.getHobby());
                },
                (list1, list2) -> {
                    if (list1.size() > 0 && list2.size() > 0
                            && list1.getLast().getName().equals(list2.getFirst().getName())) {
                        list1.getLast().getHobbies().addAll(list2.removeFirst().getHobbies());
                    }
                    list1.addAll(list2);
                });
```

But honestly, using a map, or even a simple loop, would be much cleaner and probably more efficient.

Comment: At least it meets OP's requirements.